# MYSQL covert Null value to a data type

Tags: mysql

I want to convert `NULL` value to any data type (if not possible, than 0) but I am not able to. I have used `IFNULL` and Coalesce functions but still value returned is displayed as `NULL`.

Queries:

1. `select ifnull(phone, 0) from address;`
2. `select coalesce(postal_code, 0) from address;`

Comment: It should work. How do you retrieve the data?

Comment: your issue is not with the method aka coalesce() or ifnull().. the issue is with how you are getting your data.. you don't have null values to convert apparently.. are you using a left join? or are you storing null values in the database? can you post some sample data?

Comment: here is a sample with some data.. i put in null values and used coalesce() and it works just fine. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad3c/2